# Interaction has already been acknowledged when responding to the second embed after the first embed, button discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

There's a ton of threads there already I know but I still can't get it to work. I'm building an embed with a button. The embed appears using command $test. The error happens when I trigger the embed for the second time (2nd $test) and click the button after clicking the button on the first trigger.

This flow should work but the error "Interaction has already been acknowledged" triggers.

**Steps:**

1. Type $test to show the embed.
2. User clicks "Click me." button on the embed.
3. The embed updates to embed2 confirming the click on the button.
4. Type $test again to show the embed.
5. User clicks "Click me." button on the embed.

**Result:** Interaction has already been acknowledged.

**Expected Result:** The 2nd embed should be totally new. It should not remember my first interaction on the 1st embed.

Should I use .reply() instead of .update()? Does that matter?

I read a post saying this:

> Interaction has already been acknowledged happens when you try to
> reply to the interaction that you already replied, and you can fix it
> by using .editReply() after you .reply() the interaction.

Here's the code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (command === "test") {
    const button = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId("button1")
    .setLabel("Click me.")
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
  );

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#5A5A5A")
    .setTitle("Embed")
    .setDescription("Did you receive this message? Click button if you did.")

  const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#5A5A5A")
    .setTitle("Confirmation Embed")
    .setDescription("Thanks for confirming!")

  message.channel.send({embeds:[embed], components:[button]});

  const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();

  collector.on("collect", (i) => {
    if(i.customId === "button1") {
      i.update({embeds: [embed2], components:[]});
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the collector is in the channel you should tie it to the message

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (command === "test") {
    const button = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId("button1")
    .setLabel("Click me.")
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
  );

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#5A5A5A")
    .setTitle("Embed")
    .setDescription("Did you receive this message? Click button if you did.")

  const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#5A5A5A")
    .setTitle("Confirmation Embed")
    .setDescription("Thanks for confirming!")

  const msg = await message.channel.send({embeds:[embed], components:[button]});

  const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector();

  collector.on("collect", (i) => {
    if(i.customId === "button1") {
      i.update({embeds: [embed2], components:[]});
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer the update.

This can either be done directly by replying to an interaction using `i.reply()` or by using `await i.deferUpdate();` after the button is pressed.

Since you need to edit an already existing interaction, you need to use the second option.

Example:

```
collector.on("collect", (i) => {

  if(i.customId === "button1") {
    await i.deferUpdate();
    i.update({embeds: [embed2], components:[]});
    }
})
```

Comment: This one did not work, sorry. The error from this: Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.